# How do you answer yes for yum install automatically

Tags: yum, installation, automated-install

In centos how do you answer yes automatically for yum install so that it is an unassisted install?

Answer (score 267, accepted):

You can use:

`yum -y install packagename`

The "-y" implies "yes".

The long option is `--assumeyes`

Comment: Or, if you don't like memorizing the right way to get "yes" into every program, just use `yes | yum ...`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i had no idea what `yes` was for until just now. amazing!

Comment: How to provide "No" ?

Comment: @ChamindaBandara `yes no`

Answer (score 13):

Add the following line to `/etc/yum.conf`

```
assumeyes=1
```